# Copy function only working on some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a copy function set up on my checkout page. The sole purpose of it is to copy the text that was entered for the customers shipping information that they entered and display it further down the page in a confirmation section.

It is working great for the customers name and address1 line. The address2, city, state, and zipcode line will not show up though. I have no idea why. I am doing the exact same thing as I am doing for the address1 and name. I have tried changing data-copy names, but nothing is working.

This is where the customer would enter their shipping info at.

```
<div class="shippinginfocontainer">
    <span class="summarytitle"><p>Enter Shipping Information</p> 
</span><br>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
            <div class="center"><input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" required></div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline1">Street Line 1</label>
                <div class="center"><input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipTostreetline1" data-copy="#address1" name="ShipTostreetline1" required></div>
                </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline2">Street Line 2</label>
                <div class="center"><input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" id="ShipTostreetline2" data-copy="#address2" name="ShipTostreetline2" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->streetline2); ?>"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="paddingleft" for="city">City</label>
                <div class="center"><input type="text" class="biginputbarinline" id="ShipTocity" data-copy="#confirmcity" name="ShipTocity" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->city); ?>" required></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="formleftcenter">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="state">State</label>
                    <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" id="ShipTostate" data-copy="#confirmstate" name="ShipTostate" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->state); ?>" required>
                </div>  
            <div class="formrightcenter">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" id="ShipTozipcode" name="ShipTozipcode" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->zipcode); ?>" required>
                </div>
```

I then am copying the text to here(I left the state one out):

```
<p>Shipping to:</p>
    <p><div id="name"></div></p>
    <p><div id="address1"></div></p>
    <p><div id="address2"></div></p>
    <p><div id="confirmcity"></div></p>
    <p><div id="confirmzip"></div></p>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $(".preview").on('input', function() {
    $($(this).data('copy')).html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Any idea why it is not working on those inputs?

Comment: What is the use of "data-copy" attribute?

Comment: To copy the text from that input field and show it in another place on the page.

Comment: `zipcode line will not show up though` you don't have the `.preview` class on that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have preview class in name & address 1 input field

```
<input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" required>
```

but you dont have preview class in other input fields

```
<input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" id="ShipTostreetline2" data-copy="#address2" name="ShipTostreetline2">
```

add preview in other input field classes

Answer (score 2):

You only have the 'preview' class on your full name and address1 lines.

Your jquery selector is selecting all elements on the page with the class 'preview', so the logic inside will only apply to HTML elements with the class 'preview'.

You'll want to change the rest of your inputs to also include the 'preview' class.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it's correct, although it could use a little more explanation and a fix.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I over looked that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the php part, but the HTML and jquery should look something like this:

```js
window.addAddress = function() {
    var inputs = $('input').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    });
    var i = 0;
    $.each($('.data'), function(){
        $(this).html(inputs[i]);
        i++;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shippinginfocontainer"> <span class="summarytitle"><p>Enter Shipping Information</p> 
</span>
    <br>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" value="Mickey Gordon" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline1">Street Line 1</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipTostreetline1" data-copy="#address1" name="ShipTostreetline1" value="Suite 105" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline2">Street Line 2</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline" id="ShipTostreetline2" data-copy="#address2" name="ShipTostreetline2" value="701 Rackamac Ln">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="city">City</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline" id="ShipTocity" data-copy="#confirmcity" name="ShipTocity" value="Oxnard" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formleftcenter">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" id="ShipTostate" data-copy="#confirmstate" name="ShipTostate" value="California" required>
        </div>
        <div class="formrightcenter">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" id="ShipTozipcode" name="ShipTozipcode" value="93031" required>
            </div>
            <p>Shipping to:</p>
            <p>
                <div id="name" class="data"></div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div id="address1" class="data"></div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div id="address2" class="data"></div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div id="confirmcity" class="data"></div>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div id="confirmzip" class="data"></div>
            </p>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addAddress()" />
```